# how to move next tab menu using button in lwuit?

Tags: java-me, tabs, lwuit

How to move one tab to another tab using button Click? When I click accept button, it moves to next tab menu.
Can anyone tell me how to do this?

```
    frmSubscription = new Form();

    String[] subscriptionList = {"15 Days - $12.5", "30 Days - $25", "45 Days - $37.5", "60 Days - $50", "90 Days - $75"};
    cmdBack = new Command((String)locale.get("BACK"));
    cmdExit = new Command((String)locale.get("EXIT"));
    lblLeague = new Label("Premier League");
    lblSubscription = new Label("Subscription");
    lblCurrentPlan = new Label("Current Plan");     
    comboSubscription = new ComboBox(subscriptionList);
    deviceWidth = Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth();
    btnAccept = new Button("Accept");
    btnAccept.setAlignment(Component.CENTER);
    btnAccept.setPreferredW(deviceWidth);

    btnSubscription = new Button("Unsubscription");
    btnCancel = new Button("Cancel");

    flowLayout = new FlowLayout();
    frmSubscription.setLayout(flowLayout);      

    btnTermsCond = new Button((String) locale.get("TERM&COND"));
    btnSubscribe = new Button("Subscribe");

    // Terms & conditions container 
    txtTermsCondt =  new TextArea((String) locale.get("TERMS & CONDITIONS"));
    txtTermsCondt.setEditable(false);

    termsContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    termsContainer.addComponent(txtTermsCondt);
    termsContainer.addComponent(btnAccept);

    // Subscription container       
    subContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    subContainer.addComponent(lblCurrentPlan);
    subContainer.addComponent(comboSubscription);
        acceptContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        acceptContainer.addComponent(btnSubscription);
        acceptContainer.addComponent(btnCancel);            
    subContainer.addComponent(acceptContainer);

    container = new Container();
    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(1, 2);       
    container.setLayout(gridLayout);        
    container.addComponent(lblLeague);
    container.addComponent(lblSubscription);        

    tabSubscription = new TabbedPane();     
    tabSubscription.addTab("Terms and Conditions", termsContainer );
    tabSubscription.addTab("Unsubscribe", subContainer );       


    frmSubscription.addComponent(container);
    frmSubscription.addComponent(tabSubscription);
    btnAccept.addActionListener(this);  
    frmSubscription.addCommand(cmdBack);
    frmSubscription.addCommand(cmdExit);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if tabSubscription.getSelectedIndex() == 0
   tabSubscription.setSelectedIndex(1);
else
   tabSubscription.setSelectedIndex(0);
frmSubscription.repaint();
```

Comment: Correct but I don't think you need a repaint. You might need a revalidate() if the tabs aren't in the center of a border layout and their size changes.

Comment: It is moving to next tab but it display the bottom of the tab page. How can I move up?

Comment: Thanks a lot Pheromix it is working for me and i was searching for it :D